# Using Set y How to get record in that position using FPDF

Tags: php, fpdf

[image]

Hi in the below code I am getting the above output but in that output I want to display under the ward/room Mini Room/103/01 but it was displaying under the s.i in the same way date and advance values also.

Can any one help me from this issue?

**PHP**

```
function printBodyData($header){
        global $bill_type,$dbh;
        $old_bill_type = $bill_type;
        global $res_opd,$res_adv,$res_reg,$res_ipd,$res_lab,$res_dis;
        $width = array(10,20,20,20,20,20,30,30,30);
        $this->SetLineWidth(.1);

        //printing header

        //$this->Cell(210,1,"",'T',1);
        $this->SetFont('Times','B',10);
        $this->Ln(5);
        $i=0;
        foreach($header as $column){
            $this->Cell($width[$i],9,$column,0,0,"C");  

            $i++;
        }
        $this->Ln(6);
        $this->SetFont('Times','B','10');
        $this->Cell(210,1,"",'T',1);

        //printing Body
        //echo "Billtype: ".$bill_type;
        //echo "<br> Res opd: ".$res_opd;
        $old_bill_type = $bill_type;
        $tot_opd = $tot_adv = $tot_reg = $tot_ipd = $tot_lab = 0;


        /*****************************Current In Patient STARTS***********************************/
        if($old_bill_type == "all")
            $bill_type="reg";
        if($bill_type=="reg"){
        if(count($res_opd)>0){
            $this->Ln();
            $this->SetFont('Times','B',12);
            $this->cell(50,6,"Current patient List");
            $this->Ln();
        }
        $i=1;
        foreach($res_opd as $row){  
        //$doctors = getConsultantDoctors($row['inch_doc'],$row['ipd_reg_no']);
        $doctors = array(ucwords($row['inch_doc']).", ");
        try{
            $ipd_reg_no=$row['ipd_reg_no'];
            $sql = "SELECT ab.employee_name emp_name
                    FROM address_book ab,ipd_doctor id
                    WHERE ab.employee_id = id.employee_id
                    AND id.ipd_reg_no = ipd_reg_no";

            //$sth_doc = $dbh->prepare($sql);

            $sth_doc = $dbh->query($sql);
            $all_doc = $sth_doc->fetchAll();
            foreach($all_doc as $doc){
                $doctors[] = $doc['emp_name'].", ";
            }
            $doctors = array_unique($doctors);
            //print_r($doctors);
            //$doctors = implode(" ",$doctors);
        }catch(PDOException $e){
            die($e);
        }   

            $this->SetFont('Times','',8);
            $this->cell($width[0],6,$i,0,0,'L');
            $this->cell($width[1],6,$row['reg_no'],0,0,'C');
            $this->cell($width[2],6,$row['ipd_reg_no'],0,0,'C');
            $this->cell($width[3],6,$row['first_name']." ".$row['last_name'],0,0,'L');
            $this->cell($width[4],6,getAge($row['reg_no'])."/".$row['sex'],0,0,'C');
            //$this->cell($width[5],6,ucwords($row['inch_doc']),0,0,'L');
            $i=1;
            foreach($doctors as $d){
            if(($i)>0)
            $this->SetX(110);
            $this->cell($width[5],6,$d,0,0,'L');
            if(($i)>0)
            $this->Ln();
            $i++;

            }



            $this->cell($width[6],6,$row['room_category_name']."/".$row['room_id']."/".$row['floor_no'],0,0,'L');




            //$this->cell($width[6],6,$row['room_category_name']."/".$row['room_id']."/".$row['floor_no'],0,0,'C');
            $this->cell($width[7],6,getOutputDate($row['admit_date'])."/".$row['time'],0,0,'C');

            $this->cell($width[8],6,$row['advance'],0,0,'C');
            $this->Ln();
            $i++;

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Salam. There are a few key problems with your code, all of which should be addressed.

Let's start with the [`Cell`](http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/cell.htm) method. First, you should write `Cell` with a capital `C` instead of `cell` as you currently are. In your code, you are attempting to print each doctor to the same location, as evidenced here:

```
foreach($doctors as $d){
    if(($i)>0)
        $this->SetX(110);
    $this->cell($width[5],6,$d,0,0,'L');
    if(($i)>0)
        $this->Ln();
    $i++;
}
```

This is messing up your subsequent calls to `Cell`, so I would strongly consider revising your code to that this into account. Additionally, it is possible that you aren't allocating enough cell space to print some of your information. Some of the doctors have long names, like `Dr. Shakeel Jeelani`. If the width to print the name is greater than the width of the cell you will start to see some unwanted behaviour. It may also be that the information on `1 Year/female` is larger than the cell, since the text gets very close to the cells for `Consultant`. Take a look and make sure your numbers add up and that the widths of your field do not exceed the width of the cell. FPDF has a function you can use called [`GetStringWidth`](http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/getstringwidth.htm).

Comment: I'm not here to code for you, I'm here to lead you in the right direction.